# Yii using POST, but really using GET?

Tags: php, yii

I've noticed that CGridView buttons use POST, but don't really POST anything. It makes a POST to a URL like a GET.

Example:

It POSTs empty to `site/controller/action/param1/value1/param2/value2`, while I think it should POST to `site/controller/action` and have `param1` and `param2` in `POST body`.

Is it possible to change it?

Thanks

Comment: POST is a request method, an HTTP *verb*. You don't have to add a request body to it. This is a perfectly fine POST request as far as HTTP is concerned. POST doesn't equal data in the body and GET doesn't equal URL query parameters.

Comment: well most people says that POST should be used when the request has side effects and GET as a read-only. Since the button is `Delete` and it has a side effect in the server (not idempotent), should be not accessed through URL-query.

Comment: No, it should not be a GET request. It doesn't matter whether the parameters are in the URL or request body, the important part is that the HTTP verb is POST.

Comment: Ok maybe I understood you. The important thing is the method, not the URL/params... then to avoid user entering the same URL I should check $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], right?

Comment: Yes. Your server *should* react very differently whether you `GET example.com/foo/bar/baz` or `POST example.com/foo/bar/baz`. Research "RESTful" a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Passing params as GET is used for convenience. In Yii crud, there is a `_loadModel` method to load model, and it is using `$_GET` param. However, to avoid deleting via GET, there is check if it is post request. Here is some (stripped to minimum) example:

```
private function _loadModel()
{
    // Find method uses get here, for most actions it is fine
    return User::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);
}

// Destructive action
public function actionDelete()
{
    // Check if it really comes from post
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest())
    {
        $this->_loadModel()->delete();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new CHttpException(400, 'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }
}
```

When it comes to ajax, it really does't much matter it is GET or POST, in normal request however browser will ask you to resubmit POST data when trying to refresh.

Using POST for destructive, or content changing actions was started to be recommended, when browsers started to using URL prefetching, to get faster responses. In earilier AJAX applications there was plenty of destructive actions made via get. The result of implementing URL prefetching in browsers was that these applications were deleting all records when in example viewing list:) This is the main reason for using POST over GET. But spiders might follow such url anyway. Thats why it is important on server side to check it it is really a POST request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've found that there's a `'verbs'` rule for allowing access to actions, so I'm using that now, so the delete/etc actions are checked if they come vía POST, or denied. That way I can use the Yii's parameter binding from URL into my actions and filter by POST method.